# Combine two datasets of equal length in Python

Tags: python

I've got two datasets of equal length. Both only one column. I'm trying to combine them and make one dataset with two columns.
What I've tried gives me one column with all the values from the first dataframe. But the second column is al NaN's.
Please help.

I have tried .join & .merge & pd.concat & .add & ...

```
df_low_rename = df_low_sui.rename(index=str, columns={'suicides/100k pop': 'low_gdp'})
df_high_rename = df_high_sui.rename(index=str, columns={'suicides/100k pop': 'high_gdp'})

df_combined = df_low_rename.add(df_high_rename)
df_combined
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfTBB.png)

Comment: How does your df_low_rename and df_high_rename look like. More specifically  how does their index look like ?

Comment: Both have been re-indexed. 11789 rows x 1 column

Comment: can you provide a few samples of each dataframe?e.g., `print(df_low_rename.head().to_string())`

Comment: If you could reproduce your issue with some mock datasets for people to try out and see it isn't just something with your data that could help. People have jumped to the current answers because they should work for this case.

Comment: @adrtam

low_gdp \\
0     2.39 \\
1     3.49 \\
2     2.85 \\
3     1.50 \\
4     0.62 \\

Comment: @lucasgcb, I just posted an answer to my question. Unfortunately, I forgot to re-index again after splitting my data earlier. After I did split it, the join function worked out for me.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas merge function works.

Dataset 1:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
print(df1)
```

output:

```
      Name  Age
 0    Alex   10
 1     Bob   12
 2  Clarke   13
```

Dataset 2:

```
data2 = [['Alex','Science'],['Bob','Physics'],['Clarke','Social']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['Name','Courses'])
print(df2)
```

output:

```
      Name  Courses
 0    Alex  Science
 1     Bob  Physics
 2  Clarke   Social
```

merging the datasets:

```
final=pd.merge(df1,df2)
```

output:

```
        Name  Age  Courses
   0    Alex   10  Science
   1     Bob   12  Physics
   2  Clarke   13   Social
```

Comment: I get this error if I use merge:
MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on

Comment: If you dont have any columns in common, add a new tmp column say df1['tmp']=1, df2['tmp']=1 then merge the data frames and drop the tmp column. Check this https://ibb.co/M5fPmKk

Answer (score 0):

I believe a [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) will do it for you. Something like this:

```
df_low_rename.join(df_high_rename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with concat on the column axis:

```
combined = pandas.concat([df_low_rename, df_high_rename], axis=1)
```

Comment: Actually have tried this already. Exactly how you suggetted it, but also got one culumn with only NaN’s

Comment: did you check the data? a few sample would be helpful.

Comment: I did a lot of ‘cleaning’. No empty values or non-numerical values left. Just one column with 11789 rows containing only floats.

Answer (score 0):

Both data sets didn't have the same indexes. I fixed it like this:

```
df_low_rename = df_low_rename.reset_index(drop=True)
df_high_rename = df_high_rename.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then I used the join function:

```
df_combined = df_low_rename.join(df_high_rename)
df_combined
```

This way, I got the right output. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me and I apologize for this rookie mistake.

Comment: You may mark this as an answer, glad you found your solution!